# retrieve the last recording for each patient

Tags: mysql, sql

I will want to retrieve the last id_analyse for each id_patient, I wrote this request but I have an error.

can you help me ?

```
SELECT
    id_analyse,
    id_patient AS patient_num‚
FROM
    analyses_de_risque AS an
WHERE
    id_analyse =(
    SELECT
        MAX(id_analyse)
    FROM
        analyses_de_risque
    WHERE
        id_patient = an.patient_num
)
```

here after the structure of my tabs

### --
-- Structure de la table `analyses_de_risque`

```
CREATE TABLE `analyses_de_risque` (
  `id_analyse` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_patient` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oxy_liq` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Oxygène liquide',
  `source_mobile` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Source mobile',
  `traitement_continu` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Traitement continu 24h/24',
  `sup_a_3l` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Débit ≥3l/min',
  `gazeux` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Oxygène gazeux (y compris station de remplissage) le poste de secours doit être facilement accessible',
  `traitement_associe` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Traitement associé à PPC ou VNI ou Aérosol',
  `Fumeur` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fumeur',
  `entourage_fumeur` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entourage fumeur',
  `autonome` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Autonome',
  `anxieux` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Anxieux',
  `isole` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Isolé',
  `suspicion_addiction` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Suspicion d’addiction (alcool,...)',
  `absent_mep` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Absent à la mise en place',
  `utilisation_corps_gras` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Utilise des corps gras (crème, pommade, …)',
  `domicile_prive` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Domicile privé',
  `atypique` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Logement atypique (caravane, foyer collectif, hôtel, …)',
  `insalubre` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Logement insalubre, encombré, minuscule…',
  `acces_difficile` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Logement d’accès difficile',
  `chauffage_danger` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Mode de chauffage/cuisine dangereux avec oxygène',
  `animal_danger` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Présence d''animal à griffes/dents acérées',
  `inflammable_danger` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'présence de matières inflammables (papier, bois, solvant, alcool, essence)',
  `capacitee_remplir` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Capacité à remplir le portable liquide',
  `zone_passage` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Installation hors zone de passage (hall, couloir…)',
  `aeration` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Volume ou aération du lieu de dépôt et d’utilisation suffisant',
  `materiel_non_adapte` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Matériel non adapté / Problème de manipulation',
  `comprehension` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Compréhension des consignes de sécurité par le patient ou entourage',
  `hygiene` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Respect consigne d’hygiène',
  `observance` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Observance (respect de la prescription débit / durée )',
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `commentaire` text,
  `vu_pharmacien` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `commentaire_pharmacien` text,
  `date_pharmacien` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `visite_a_faire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



--
```

### -- Structure de la table `patient`

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `id_patient` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cli_chrono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_user_technician` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone2_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone3_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone3` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email1_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email1` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email2_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city1` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1_com` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2_com` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code3` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city3` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3_com` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `ss_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_address` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_postal_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_city` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_orga` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ss_right` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_address` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_postal_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_city` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_orga` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_right` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_num` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutu_number_member` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hospitalization` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `hospi_enter` date NOT NULL,
  `hospi_leave` date NOT NULL,
  `died` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `died_date` date NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `personnalsContact` longtext NOT NULL,
  `nom_prenom_concat` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `covid19` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `non_patient` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gazeux_interdit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doublon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'si oui empecher l''utilisation de ce compte',
  `id_patient_dedoublonage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `espace_patient_actif` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `espace_patient_code` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patient_a_probleme` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `injoignable` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='liste des patients';
```

Comment: Please add full error message (edit question)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the aliased column from your main query an.patient_num

use original column name  an.id_patient

Answer (score 0):

The best method is `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT id_analyse,
       id_patient AS patient_num‚
  FROM analyses_de_risque AS an
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM analyses_de_risque anin
        WHERE anin.id_patient = an.id_patient and anin.id_analyse > an.id_analyse)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code.  You have a dangling comma and there is no `patient_num` in the tables.  You cannot refer to the alias in the `SELECT`.

I would also recommend qualifying *all* column references and giving the tables meaningful aliases:

```
SELECT ar.id_analyse, ar.id_patient AS patient_num
FROM analyses_de_risque ar
WHERE ar.id_analyse = (SELECT MAX(ar2.id_analyse)
                       FROM analyses_de_risque ar2
                       WHERE ar2.id_patient = ar.patient_num
                      );
```